# Detect a Non Responding Process

Tags: c#, qt

I'm trying to detect if a process I'm launching via my C# program still answers or not.

I've tryed the following :

```
Process *notepads[];
notepads = Process::GetProcessesByName("Notepad.exe");

// Test to see if the process is responding.
if (notepads[0]->Responding())
   notepads[0]->CloseMainWindow();
else
   notepads[0]->Kill();
```

However, I would like to find a Qt equivalent for ANY process (not only MMI processes).

Do you know how I could do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting process list is OS-dependent. so you have to do it by yourself on each platform.
on Windows, you can use Windows API [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#process_enumeration_functions)
on Linux, you can search /proc folder.

Answer (score 0):

See [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qprocess.html) documentation for details.

Qt does not provide any method to obtain information or control overs process that you don't explicitely start from a `QProcess` instance.